# Use $regex inside $expr in mongodb aggregation

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, expr

My doc looks as follows

```
doc = {
    name: 'abc',
    age:20
}
```

and my query looks like

```
{ $expr: {$and:[{ $gt:[ "$age",  10 ] },
                { $regex:["$name",'ab']}
               ]
          }
} }
```

But it's not working and I get an error

> Unrecognized expression '$regex'

How can I make it work?

My original query looks like this

```
db.orders.aggregate([{
$match: {}},
{$lookup: {
    from: "orders",
    let: {
        "customer_details": "$customerDetails"
    },
    pipeline: [
        {
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                        $and: [
                                { $or: [
                                                {
                                                $eq: ["$customerDetails.parentMobile","$$customer_details.parentMobile"]
                                                },
                                                {$eq: ["$customerDetails.studentMobile","$$customer_details.parentMobile"]
                                                },
                                                {$eq: ["$customerDetails.studentMobile","$$customer_details.parentMobile"]
                                                },
                                                {$eq: ["$customerDetails.studentMobile","$$customer_details.studentMobile"]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                {$eq: ["$customerDetails.zipCode","$$customer_details.zipCode"]},
                                {$eq: ["$customerDetails.address","$$customer_details.address"]}
                        ]
                    }

            }
        }],
    as: "oldOrder"
}
}])
```

I want to use `regex` for matching `address`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you add a sample of the data?, it seems you do the lookup from the same collection "orders"?

Answer (score 8):

[**`$regex`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) is a query operator you cannot use inside [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) because it only supports aggregation pipeline operators.

```
{
  "$expr": { "$gt": ["$age", 10] } ,
  "name": { "$regex": "ab" }
}
```

If you have mongodb  **4.2**, you can use [**`$regexMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/)

```
{ "$expr": {
  "$and": [
    { "$gt": ["$age", 10] },
    {
      "$regexMatch": {
        "input": "$name",
        "regex": "ab", //Your text search here
        "options": "i",
      }
    }
  ]
}}
```

Comment: How can do fuzzy matching inside expr , because I'm using $and inside $expr

Comment: Above query will satisfy the `$and` condition. BTW what is your mongodb version?

Comment: problem with $regexMatch is , I'm using this $expr inside match of `$lookup` , inside $lookup i'm using variable declaration and using those variable inside $regexMatch as `$regexMatch: {input :"$name" , regex:"$$NAME"}` where `NAME` is variable declared in $lookup

Comment: @ganesh this is working https://mongoplayground.net/p/kwMV8iHIVQK

Comment: Pls show your actual documents and query then only I can help.

Answer (score 5):

If your mongoDB version is 4.2, then you can use `$regexMatch`

try this

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $gt: [
          "$age",
          10
        ]
      },
      {
        $regexMatch: {
          input: "$name",
          regex: "ab"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

check this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1DKmQATcOJo)

Comment: what if i want to pass `"ab"` as a variable like `"$$name"` not a hardcoded string

Comment: Could you add the whole query to the question?

Comment: and a sample of your data, and the expected output too